# Adding layers to an OpenLayers map from a WPS process automatically after processing

Tags: openlayers-2, wps, geonode

I want to process two layers visible from a an OpenLayers client map interface such as Geonode and then add the result of the output directly to the map automatically after the processing is finished. is there anyone who would have a general description of how to go about it. I have medium level knowledge in OpenLayers.